# How to add Page Numbers for each printed page SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I want to make it so that when you print a page in SSRS, it will correctly show you the number of each page you print out. Is that possible in ssrs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply add a footer (or header) to your report and use the `Globals!PageNumber` and/or `Globals!TotalPages` in a textbox. You can combine the two as well. So, add a footer to the report, add a new textbox and set the expression to

> ="page " & Globals!PageNumber & " of " & Globals!TotalPages

Note: The page numbers will differ from viewing on screen to printing as the interactive size is not always the same as the printed size.